# RadioButtons from ipywidgets worked last week, but not rendering correctly now

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, ipywidgets

**EDIT:** I just discovered that the issue below does not appear when switching to the `ipykernel` environment in Jupyter Notebooks.

---

I am using Jupyter Notebooks. Yesterday I had to create a new environment for my project. I did not save a .yml file of my previous environment so today I had to manually install all packages from zero. A few minutes ago I re-installed `ipywidgets` through Conda to run a few widgets:

```
(my-env) C:\Users\name>conda install ipywidgets
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\name\miniconda3\envs\my-env

  added / updated specs:
    - ipywidgets


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ipywidgets-8.0.4           |  py311haa95532_0         254 KB
    jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.5   |  py311haa95532_0         179 KB
    widgetsnbextension-4.0.5   |  py311haa95532_0         862 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.3 MB
```

And I have the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML

variable_list = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3', 'Element 4']

# widget
buttons = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=variable_list,
    description='Select Element:',
)

# label widget to display the selected element
output_label = widgets.Label()

# global variable to store the selected element
selected_element_var = None

# update the label and the global variable when an element is selected from the buttons
def on_buttons_change(change):
    global selected_element_var
    selected_element_var = change['new']
    output_label.value = f"Selected Element: {selected_element_var}"

# attach function to the buttons widget
buttons.observe(on_buttons_change, names='value')

# display buttons
display(buttons, output_label)
```

I cannot remember which version of `ipywidgets` I had last week, but something definitely changed because I did not modify the code and 8 days ago it worked as expected: it showed me a list of buttons, and the value assigned to the button I pressed then got stored in `selected_element_var`.

But today the buttons are not showing, instead I get the following output:

```
RadioButtons(description='Select Element:', options=('Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3', 'Element 4'), valu…
Label(value='')
```

How can I get it to work again?